# Split second column of two column data set and append to bottom

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

So I have two columns of data of the form above. The first column is just a single EAN but the second column can have comma OR underscore separated ASIN values (so e.g. ASIN1_ASIN2 or ASIN1,ASIN2).

I would like to split each ASIN in the ASIN column and then append it to the bottom of the data set alongside its corresponding EAN (and at same time replace the original row).

So for row 68 below the appended data to the bottom would be:

```
738678181690 B00EUTKDQS

738678181690 B000KEIPC6

738678181690 B01IAEN1PI
```

And this will replace the original row 68 so that that doesn't exist anymore.

I guess the first step is using SPLIT but struggling to think of how to do it for the entire data set (especially given that ASIN column can be one ASIN, two ASINs (separated by the comma or _, three ASINs, or sometimes even four).

Comment: If you wish for the desired output to happen dynamically within your original data columns its best to seek help from `[google-apps-script]` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your EANs in A2:A & your ESINs in B2:B, try:

```
=arrayformula(query(split(flatten(A2:A&"|"&trim(split(B2:B,"_,",1))),"|"),"where Col2 is not null",0))
```

EDIT
To ensure colA is numeric:

```
=arrayformula(query(split(flatten(n(A2:A)&"|"&trim(split(B2:B,"_,",1))),"|"),"where Col2 is not null",0))
```

Comment: This works - one follow up question, the data in column A is numeric however the resulting data (after using the above) is not. Do you know why and how I can fix this? I verified this by using ISNUMBER() on both the initial data and the final data.

Comment: Try the updated formula I've just added.